# AWS Athena date_Part

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, presto, amazon-athena

I'm trying to truncate the date to just the day using Athena. 
Here's what the input and select statement look like:

```
create table ...
usagestartdate timestamp,
usageneddate timestamp,
 ...
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
'serialization.format' = ',',
'field.delim' = ',',
"timestamp.formats" = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSS'Z'") 
LOCATION 's3:

then to get just the day

select...
resource string
day(usagestartdate)
sum(usagehours)
```

Comment: https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html

Answer (score 2):

To retrieve the date of your timestamp column you need to use the datetime functions from the underlying PrestoDB engine.

So the resulting select would look like this:

```
select date(usagestartdate) date,
       date_diff('hour',usagestartdate,usageenddate) hours
from usagetable
```